# Where to find MSBuild 14.0 x64

Tags: c#, command-line, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I'm setting up a script that builds my C# solution from command-line. It works fine, but currently it runs MSBuild as 32-bit application and I want it to be ran as 64-bit.

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I can't find how to run MSBuild as 64-bit executable.

First I tried to use `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe`, but this is wrong version.

So I found `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` which is version 14.0 (now I have both Visual Studio 2015 and Microsoft Build Tools 2015 installed), but it runs as 32-bit application (or I'm missing something)?

I expected to see some .exe in `C:\Program Files` where other 64-bit exes are stored, but nothing there.

My machine is 64-bit Quad Intel Xeon.

Maybe before calling MSBuild I should call some cmd-file to setup environment properly? Like `vcvarsqueryregistry.bat`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, yes it was like in VS 2012 and VS 2013 in amd64 subfolder:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe`